# Drawing circular paths in random locations (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, random

How can I draw circular paths as shown below in random locations (randomly spaced in the `x` and `y` directions)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border = 0.12cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,snakes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x = 4.5in, y = 2in]
\fill [blue!20] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,0.5) -- (0,0.5) -- cycle;

\foreach \x in {0.05,0.075,0.25,0.35,0.45,0.55,0.65,0.85}
  \draw [>=stealth,->] (\x,0.1) arc (280:0:.1cm) -- +(283:0.05cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May they overlap?

Comment: Instead of `\fill [blue!20] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,0.5) -- (0,0.5) -- cycle;`, you can use  `\fill [blue!20] (0,0) rectangle (1,0.5);`.

Comment: @Jake No they should not overlap

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the poisson disc sampling library (you can get it in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185423/12571)).

You need to copy/paste the content of `poisson.sty` and `poisson.lua` from that answer into two files with these names. You need also a working `lualatex` to compile.

Then, using it, you can compile the following code (this one requires PGF=>3.0, see later on for other examples that work with PGF<3.0)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{poisson}
\begin{document}
\edef\mylist{\poissonpointslist{5}{5}{0.5}{20}}

\tikzset{
    circular arrow/.pic={
      \draw [>=stealth,->] (0,0.1) arc (280:0:.1cm) -- +(283:0.05cm);
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \foreach \x/\y in \mylist {
         \path (\x,\y) pic {circular arrow};
     }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

The line `\edef\mylist{\poissonpointslist{5}{5}{0.5}{20}}` is the one which creates the random coordinates to place each pic. You can change the parameters: the first two are the width an height of the rectangle in which the coordinates will be placed. The third one (0.5) is the minimum distance allowed between the random coordinates. The last one (20) is used internally by the algorithm and provides a trade-off between speed and results, and usually it is set to a value between 15 or 30.

Here is another example in which the arrows are more densely packed, and which does not use `pic` (and thus it compiles with PGF<3.0, but still requires lualatex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{poisson}
\begin{document}
\edef\mylist{\poissonpointslist{5}{5}{0.25}{20}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
     \foreach \x/\y in \mylist {
         \draw[>=stealth, ->] (\x,\y) arc (280:0:.1cm) -- +(283:0.05cm);
     }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Second example]

## Update

To create the rectangle you provided in your example, I would use the same scale in `x` and `y`, to enforce the even distribution of the centers. Also, the size of the area to be filled by the algorithm should be a bit smaller than your filled rectangle (because the algorithm only generates coordinates, not knowing in advance the size of the pictures you will draw at each coordinate). So, for example:

```
\edef\mylist{\poissonpointslist{4.4}{0.9}{0.2}{20}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in, y=1in]
    \fill[blue!20] (0,0) rectangle (4.5,1);
     \foreach \x/\y in \mylist {
         \draw[>=stealth, ->] (.02,0.02) +(\x,\y) arc (280:0:.1cm) -- +(283:0.05cm);
     }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This example does not require PGF3.0, and produces:

[image: Result]

Comment: This does not work on mine. Is there a method that does not require lualatex and PGF>=3.0

Comment: @KatyB The last two examples _do not require_ PGF 3.0. This requirement is only for the first one which uses `pic`. Lualatex is however required to compile, but as long as you have lualatex installed, there are no other dependencies, so _it should work_. What problem in particular did you have? I edited the question to give some more instructions and clarifications.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative method, which is *much* slower and leads to *much* less appealing results than JLDiaz's Poisson sampling is the brute force one from [tikz: Distribute evenly and randomly circles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87497/tikz-distribute-evenly-and-randomly-circles). The only advantage is that this doesn't require `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\xlist{4}
\def\ylist{4}

\newcommand{\fillrandomly}[4]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\diameter{#3*2}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (#1,#2);
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#4}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{0.5*#3+rnd*(#1-#3)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{0.5*#3+rnd*(#2-#3)}
        \xdef\collision{0}
        \foreach \element [count=\i] in \xlist{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i-1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\checkdistance{ sqrt( ({\xlist}[\j]-(\x))^2 + ({\ylist}[\j]-(\y))^2 ) }
            \ifdim\checkdistance pt<\diameter pt
                \xdef\collision{1}
                \breakforeach
            \fi
        }
        \ifnum\collision=0
            \xdef\xlist{\xlist,\x}
            \xdef\ylist{\ylist,\y}
            \draw [>=stealth,->] (\x,\y) ++(280:#3) arc (280:0:#3) -- +(283:0.05cm);
        \fi 

    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\fillrandomly{10}{4}{0.1}{50}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```