# How to use special colour in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I am trying to code the above picture, especially the dots inside the rectangle.

This is my current code, but it does not look like the intended figure. How can I change my code to obtain the desired output?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5);
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}
    \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
\foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
\draw [ultra thick,blue] (2,0) rectangle (3,2);
 \node at (2.5,1){patch};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Junior `percusse` detected...

Answer (score 7):

A bit kludgy but if randomness is required than a `path picture` is one way to go. Note that for low sparseness the compilation time increases dramatically. One solution to this would be to create a separate largish standalone document and then use `\includegraphics` with trimming.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  random dots/.style={
    path picture={
      \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}%
        {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}%
      \pgfgetlastxy\pathwidth\pathheight
      \tikzset{shift=(path picture bounding box.center)}
      \def\sparseness{#1}
      \pgfmathparse{int(\pathwidth/\sparseness+2)}\let\m=\pgfmathresult
      \pgfmathparse{int(\pathheight/\sparseness+2)}\let\n=\pgfmathresult
      \foreach \i in {-\m,...,\m}
        \foreach \j in {-\n,...,\n}  
          \fill [shift={(\i*\sparseness,\j*\sparseness)}, shift={(rand*\sparseness/2,rand*\sparseness/2)}, every random dot/.try]
           (0,0) circle [radius=1pt];
    }
  },
  random dots/.default=5pt,
  every random dot/.style={fill=red}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [ultra thick,blue, random dots]      (0,0) rectangle ++(1,2);
\draw [ultra thick,blue, random dots=10pt] (2,0) rectangle ++(1,2);
\draw [ultra thick,blue, random dots=2pt]  (4,0) rectangle ++(1,2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach for randomness using waves decoration (those "things" in the original picture look like small waves to me) and loops:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={waves,radius=.8mm, segment length=2mm, angle=5mm}]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5);
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}
    \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
\foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};

\foreach \i in {290,110,80,40}
\foreach \l in {250,90,330}
\foreach \m in {1,7}{
\node(a)[blue,fit={(2,0) (3,2)},inner sep=-\m pt]{};
\draw [thick,decorate,red,line cap=round](a.\l) to (a.\i);
}

\draw [ultra thick,blue] (2,0) rectangle (3,2) node (b)[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=2pt,midway,fill=white] {patch};
\draw [blue,<->,thick](b.south west)--(b.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here a quick attempt using the `patterns`-library of `tikz`. There are much more possibilities to draw this image.  I just used a white background for the `patch`-label, but there might be much more sophisticated solutions. For example one could choose inverted clipping to make the pattern around the `patch`-label fading to white/opaque.

Furthermore i threw one of your loops away, so the axes-ticks are drawn within one loop.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  % axes and x-/y-ticks
  \draw [>=latex, <->, thick] (0,5) -- (0,0) -- (5,0);
  \foreach \x in {1,...,4} {
   \draw (\x,-2pt) -- ++(0,4pt) node [below=.1cm] {\scriptsize $\x$};
   \draw (-2pt,\x) -- ++(4pt,0) node [left=.1cm] {\scriptsize $\x$};
  }
  % rectangle with pattern and patch
  \draw [ultra thick, blue, fill, pattern=crosshatch dots, pattern color=red] (2,0) rectangle (3,2);
  \draw [thick, blue, >=latex, <->] (2,1) -- (3,1) node [midway, above=.1cm, fill=white, inner sep=0pt] {\scriptsize patch}; 
  % x-labels
  \draw [thick, dashed] (2.5,0) -- ++(0,-.5) node [below] {$X_1$};
  \draw [thick, dashed] (0,0) -- ++(0,-.5) node [below] {$X_0=0$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Rendered image:

[image: rendered image]

> **EDIT** Change colors

As the initial question was *how to use special colour* here some additional information about colors.

If you use `dvipsnames` as option in your `\documentclass` or do an `\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}` you can use the `dvips`-colors. For an overview visit [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#The_68_standard_colors_known_to_dvips).

If you need more control about your colors you can play around with them by using e.g.

```
red
red!75
red!75!blue
```

to set the saturation of a color or mix colors up.

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=25pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\psLoop{25}{
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=monkey](8,4)
    \psRandom[dotsize=2pt,randomPoints=500,color](6,0)(8,4){\psframe(6,0)(8,4)}
    \psline(0,4)(0,0)(8,0)
    \psxTick(0){X_0=0}\psxTick(7){X_1}
    \pcline[nodesep=2pt]{<->}(6,2)(8,2)\naput{patch}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help guys. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can not run the code, I have an error (! Undefined control sequence.<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps \end{pspicture}})). How can I define this one.

Comment: @pecusse try compiling with `xelatex`.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like another use case for my [poisson disc sampling library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185419/poisson-disc-sampling-implemented-in-luatex):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{poisson}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{ % Define the shape of each little mark
    pattern/.pic = {
        \draw[red!50!black] (-0.1,0) to[out=360*rnd,in=360*rnd] (0.1*rnd,0);
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0);
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}
        \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}
        \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
    % Generate the random coordinates for each little mark, using
    % poisson disc sampling (over a rectangle of 1x2, minimum distance
    % between marks of 0.1)
    \edef\mylist{\poissonpointslist{1}{2}{0.1}{25}}
    \foreach \x/\y in \mylist {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{60*rnd}
        \path ($(\x,\y)+ (2,0)$) pic[scale=0.4,rotate=\angle] {pattern};
    }
    \draw [ultra thick,blue] (2,0) rectangle +(1,2);
    \node[fill=white, inner sep=1pt] at (2.5,1){patch};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Compiling with `lualatex` and the latest pgf libraries, you'll get:

[image: Result]