# Filling an area with a pattern between two curves (without an equation)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

How could we add the cross-and-dash pattern as the following figure?

[image]

Part of my code so far is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
    \usepackage{tkz-fct} \usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (1.7, 1.5) to[out=90,in=180] (5.8, 5.2);
\draw (.7, 1.5) to[out=90,in=180] (5.8, 3.5) ;
    \draw[->, very thick] (0,0) -- (6,0);
    \draw[->, very thick] (0,0) -- (0,6);
\fill (2.17,3.215) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[dashed] (2.17,3.215)--(2.17,0);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Could you please have a look to [Filling specified area by random dots in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145969/13304) if it helps?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This approach uses the `pgfplots` `fillbetween` library without requiring you to switch to using `pgfplots`' `axis` environment.

I also used the `intersections` library to avoid the need to manually specify the intersection point.

Suitable pattern definitions are left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,patterns,pgfplots.fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick,name path=thick] 
    (1.7, 1.5) to[out=90,in=180] (5.8, 5.2);
  \draw[name path=thin] 
    (.7, 1.5) to[out=90,in=180] (5.8, 3.5) ;
  \draw[->, very thick] (0,0) -- (6,0);
  \draw[->, very thick] (0,0) -- (0,6);
  \fill[name intersections={of=thick and thin, by={intersect}}] 
    (intersect) circle (1.5pt);
  \draw[dashed] (intersect) -- (intersect |- 0,0);
  \tikzfillbetween[
    of=thick and thin,split,
    every even segment/.style={pattern=crosshatch}
  ] {pattern=grid};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could something like \draw[pattern=horizontal lines] (intersect) --..; this work? I'd like to avoid compiling my tex with XeLaTeX and remain with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: What about this requires XeLaTeX? I produced the output above using pdfLaTeX.

Comment: You're right. There was a clash with xcolor package and I couldn't do it with pdfLaTeX.

Answer (score 18):

Like this? (using [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) and its `fillbetween` library)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=left,
xmin=1,
ymin=-1
]
\addplot+[name path=A,no marks,samples=100,domain=1.2:3,black] {4*ln(x)};
\addplot+[name path=B,no marks,samples=100,domain=1.2:3,black] {x^2*ln(x)};
\addplot fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=1:3},
        split,
        every segment no 0/.style={pattern=north east lines,pattern color=gray},
        every segment no 1/.style={pattern=fivepointed stars,pattern color=gray},];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Argh, you're too fast! :-) I wasted time figuring how to use `fillbetween` outside `axis`.

Comment: @PaulGessler, I guess that Gonzalo is one of the PGF developers. lol

Answer (score 7):

Here's a slightly more random attempt with [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) using a very rudimentary implementation of a Poisson disc sampling [algorithm](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph07-poissondisk.pdf) which I hope captures the spirit of the OP request.

[image]

This is a much longer routine than I'd normally attempt in MP - I would welcome suggestions for improvements or bug fixes.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

% Fill "shape" with "mark" using Poisson Disc 
% Sampling with radius "r" and trial placements "k".
% Smaller "r" and larger "k" are slower.
vardef pds_fill(expr shape, mark, r, k) =
    save w, h, diagonal, cellsize, imax, jmax, m, n, far_enough_away, 
         a, p, g, random, temp, trial, xx, yy, ii, jj, output;
    clearxy;
    numeric w, h, cellsize, imax, jmax, g[], m, n; 
    pair diagonal;
    diagonal = urcorner shape - llcorner shape;
    w = xpart diagonal;
    h = ypart diagonal;
    cell_size := r/sqrt(2);

    imax := floor(w/cell_size);
    jmax := floor(h/cell_size);
    for i = -1 upto 1+imax:
      for j = -1 upto 1+jmax:
        g[i][j] := -1;
      endfor
    endfor

    z0 = center shape;
    g[floor(x0/cell_size)][floor(y0/cell_size)] := 0; 
    m := 0; % index of marks made
    n := 0; % index of active points
    a[n] = m;
    boolean far_enough_away;
    pair p[];
    forever:
      exitif n<0;
      % shuffle a[0..n]
      for i=n step -1 until 0:
        random := floor uniformdeviate i;
        temp := a[i]; a[i] := a[random]; a[random] := temp;
      endfor
      % now a[n] is our random point
      trial := 0;
      forever:
         % find a trial point
         trial := trial+1;
         exitif trial>k;
         p0 := z[a[n]];
         p[trial] := p0 shifted (r+uniformdeviate r,0) rotatedabout(p0,uniformdeviate 360);
         xx := xpart p[trial];
         yy := ypart p[trial];
         % test it if it is inside the shape's bbox
         if  (xpart llcorner shape < xx) and (xx < xpart urcorner shape)
         and (ypart llcorner shape < yy) and (yy < ypart urcorner shape):
             ii := floor(xx/cell_size);
             jj := floor(yy/cell_size);
             far_enough_away := true;
             for i=ii-1 upto ii+1:
               for j=jj-1 upto jj+1:
                 if known g[i][j]:
                    if (g[i][j] > -1):
                       if (x[g[i][j]] - xx) ++ (y[g[i][j]] - yy) < r:
                          far_enough_away := false;
                       fi
                    fi
                 fi
               endfor
             endfor
         else:
           far_enough_away := false;
         fi
         exitif far_enough_away;
      endfor

      if far_enough_away:
        m := m+1;
        n := n+1;
        z[m] = p[trial];
        a[n] := m;
        g[ii][jj] := m;
      else:
        n := n-1; % ie remove a[n] from next shuffle
      fi
    endfor
    % now we have the "m" points we need
    picture output; output = image(for i=0 upto m: draw mark shifted z[i]; endfor);
    clip output to shape;
    draw output;
enddef;


beginfig(1);
u = 1cm;
path p[]; 
p1 = ((1,1) {up} .. {right} (10,6)) scaled u;
p2 = ((3,1) {up} .. {right} (10,10)) scaled u;

path xx, yy;
xx = origin -- right scaled 11u;
yy = origin -- up    scaled 11u;
drawarrow xx withcolor .5 white;
drawarrow yy withcolor .5 white;

path A, B;
A = buildcycle(p1,p2,xx shifted (0,u)); 
B = buildcycle(p1,p2,yy shifted (10u,0)); 
fill A withcolor .8[red,white];
fill B withcolor .8[blue,white];
pds_fill(A, btex $-$ etex, 10, 10);
pds_fill(B, btex $+$ etex, 10, 10);
draw p1; draw p2;

endfig;
end.
```

Answer (score 5):

Done with [`mfpic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfpic).

I used the `\tile` environment to create the `starred` tiling pattern and the `\tess{}` command to fill the second closed region with this pattern. The hatching of the first closed region is done with the `\lhatch` command (lines going from upper left to lower right). The intersection is automatically found by `mfpic`, or rather by MetaPost since `mfpic` is in fact an interface to this program (or to METAFONT).

Edit: I've replaced the starred pattern by one made of crosses, as it seems to be wished by the OP.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[metapost]{mfpic}
\setlength{\mfpicunit}{1cm}
\opengraphsfile{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{mfpic}[4][4]{0}{2}{0}{2}
    \begin{tile}{crossed, 1bp, 7, 7, false}
        \plotsymbol[3bp]{Cross}{origin}
    \end{tile}
    \setmfarray{path}{P}{(0.5, 0.25){up}.. (\xmax, 1.7){right}, 
        (0.15, 0.25){up}..(\xmax, 1){right}}
    \lhatch\lclosed
    \begin{connect}
        \mfobj{P1 cutafter P2}\mfobj{reverse P2 cutbefore P1}
    \end{connect}
    \tess{crossed}\lclosed
    \begin{connect}
        \mfobj{reverse P1 cutafter P2}\mfobj{P2 cutbefore  P1}
    \end{connect}
    \mfobj{P1}\mfobj{P2}
    \doaxes{xy}
\end{mfpic}
\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

The `.tex` file is to be typeset with LaTeX (whatever the engine), then the resulting `.mp` file with MetaPost and then again the `.tex` file with LaTeX.

[image]