# Filling an area with a pattern between two freehand curves in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

I want to fill up the area of the bounded region of the two curves by pattern lines.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [cyan, xshift=0cm] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (0,1.5) (0.7,2.3) (1.6,1.1) (2.5,1.9)   (3,2)};

 \draw [cyan, xshift=0cm] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (0,2.5) (0.4,2.4) (1,1) (2.4,2.6) (2.7,0.9) (3,1)};
 %\draw [thin, dashed,draw=gray!50!blue!30] (0,0) grid (3,3);
 \draw (0,3)--(0,0)node[below]{$0$} --(3,0)node[below]{$1$}--(3,3);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

I have found some example from [Graphics: Area between curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164773/graphics-area-between-curves). But failed in this case. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean something like (inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228630/filling-an-area-with-a-pattern-between-two-curves-without-an-equation?rq=1)):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [cyan, xshift=0cm, name path=one] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (0,1.5) (0.7,2.3) (1.6,1.1) (2.5,1.9)   (3,2)};

 \draw [cyan, xshift=0cm,name path=two] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (0,2.5) (0.4,2.4) (1,1) (2.4,2.6) (2.7,0.9) (3,1)};
 %\draw [thin, dashed,draw=gray!50!blue!30] (0,0) grid (3,3);
 \draw (0,3)--(0,0)node[below]{$0$} --(3,0)node[below]{$1$}--(3,3);
  \tikzfillbetween[
    of=one and two,split
  ] {pattern=grid};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To change the pattern simply change the `pattern` value in the `tikzfillbetween` command, ie

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [cyan, xshift=0cm, name path=one] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (0,1.5) (0.7,2.3) (1.6,1.1) (2.5,1.9)   (3,2)};

 \draw [cyan, xshift=0cm,name path=two] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (0,2.5) (0.4,2.4) (1,1) (2.4,2.6) (2.7,0.9) (3,1)};
 %\draw [thin, dashed,draw=gray!50!blue!30] (0,0) grid (3,3);
 \draw (0,3)--(0,0)node[below]{$0$} --(3,0)node[below]{$1$}--(3,3);
  \tikzfillbetween[
    of=one and two,split
  ] {pattern=north west lines};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

for

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. How can I change pappern style? @Moriambar

Comment: @MdKutubuddinSardar you have to change the `pattern` value, as I indicated in the edit. To see which pattern to use, I suggest you browse through `tikz` documentation