# Filling the intersection of paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, tikz-path

I am aware that there is myriad of posts dealing with the intersection of objects in tikz, but I haven't found one that shows how to intersect two paths, so far. I would like to either shade or hatch the intersection of two blobs:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,intersections,fillbetween,patterns}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[name path = A,draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, fill=blue]
(0,2) .. (3,3) .. (4,-3) .. (5,1);
\path[name path = B,draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, fill=red,xshift=3cm, yshift=-1cm, fill opacity=.5]
(.5,.5) .. (2,4) .. (.5,4) .. (-1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since couldn't see how to use `\clip` with `\path`, and following the examples on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369111/filling-an-area-with-a-pattern-between-two-freehand-curves-in-tikz?rq=1), I thought `fillbetween` might have been the answer, but adding

```
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B,split] {pattern=north west lines};
```

produces

[image]

and I think I see why. How can I hatch/shade the intersection only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, a solution with `\clip`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, fill=red,xshift=3cm, yshift=-1cm,fill opacity=0.5]
        (0.5,0.5) .. (2,4) .. (.5,4) .. (-1,2);
\path[use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, fill=blue]
        (0,2) .. (3,3) .. (4,-3) .. (5,1);
\begin{scope}
\clip[use Hobby shortcut, closed=true, xshift=3cm, yshift=-1cm]
        (0.5,0.5) .. (2,4) .. (.5,4) .. (-1,2);
\path[use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, pattern=north west lines,preaction={fill=red,opacity=0.5}]
        (0,2) .. (3,3) .. (4,-3) .. (5,1);
\end{scope}
\path[draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true]
        (0,2) .. (3,3) .. (4,-3) .. (5,1);
\path[draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true,xshift=3cm, yshift=-1cm]
        (0.5,0.5) .. (2,4) .. (.5,4) .. (-1,2); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Yes, I didn't quite know how to implement the \clip command. Thanks for the example!