# Monte Carlo Method Drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, circles

I would like to produce a Monte-Carlo-Plot with tikz and pgfplots, similar to [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Pi_30K.gif):

[image]

I've already tried to adapt from this thread:

[Filling specified area by random dots in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145969/filling-specified-area-by-random-dots-in-tikz)

I've tried defining the quarter-circle as a function (y=sqrt(1-x^2). Looks kind of ugly.

So I've tried the method submitted by Claudio Fiandrino.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [-latex, thick] (0, 0) -- (0, 6) node  [above] {\Large{$y$}};
\draw [-latex, thick] (0, 0) -- (6, 0) node  [right] {\Large{$x$}};
\draw [thick] (0, 5) -- (5, 5);
\draw [thick] (5, 0) -- (5, 5);

\draw [thick] (5,0 ) arc (0:90:5);

\clip (5, 0) arc (0:90:5)--++(5,0) arc(160:320:0); 
\drawdiagram[
 num points=600,
 use points equal width,
 point width=0.5pt,
 point fill color=blue,
 random point diagram] at (0, 0){};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

This is as far as I got. How do I get red dot in the other area?
I just want a plain plot, no animation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 5):

You can also generate points and evaluate them with pgfmathparse.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natural, table, fixpdftex, hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,matrix,calc}

%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2pt}%
%%%>

\def\x{0}
\def\y{0}
\def\k{0}
\def\radius{5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=gray, opacity=0.1] (\radius,0) arc(0:90:\radius) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[gray, opacity=0.25] (0,0) rectangle (\radius,\radius);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1.1*\radius,0);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1.1*\radius);
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,1000}{%
        \typeout{Point \i}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\radius*rnd}%
        \typeout{X \x}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{\radius*rnd}%
        \typeout{Y \y}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\k{(pow(\x,2)+pow(\y,2)) <pow(\radius,2)}%
        \typeout{im Kreis?: \k}%
        \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\k==1,"red","blue")}%
        \fill[\pgfmathresult] (\x,\y)circle(0.5pt);%
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

cheers!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two different clipping with the help of scopes:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [-latex, thick] (0, 0) -- (0, 6) node  [above] {\Large{$y$}};
\draw [-latex, thick] (0, 0) -- (6, 0) node  [right] {\Large{$x$}};
\draw [thick] (0, 5) -- (5, 5);
\draw [thick] (5, 0) -- (5, 5);

\draw [thick] (5,0 ) arc (0:90:5);

\begin{scope}
    \clip (5, 0) arc (0:90:5)--++(5,0) arc(160:320:0); 
    \node[
         num points=600,
         use points equal width,
         point width=0.5pt,
         point fill color=blue,
         random point diagram] at (0, 0){};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
    \clip (5, 0) arc (0:90:5)  -- (0,0) -- cycle; 
    \node[
         num points=600,
         use points equal width,
         point width=0.5pt,
         point fill color=red,
         random point diagram] at (0, 0){};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please complete the snippet to a full document example.