# Fill an ellipse with random dots

Tags: tikz-pgf

For a paper, I must draw an ellipse, which is filled by random dots in a coordinate system.

Of course it isn't a problem to draw an ellipse and the coordinate system. Also I know the function "rand" to create random dots in combination with "only marks". How is it possible to create these (random) dots in an ellipse?

Comment: Related: [Filling specified area by random dots in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145969/filling-specified-area-by-random-dots-in-tikz)

Answer (score 13):

Here's a very, very easy one. Some (or, in worst case, all) points might be invisible as they are hidden. You can alter `\pgfmathsetseed` to get another distribution or comment it out to get a new distribution on every run.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) ellipse (4 and 2);
\clip (0,0) ellipse (4 and 2);
\pgfmathsetseed{24122015}
\foreach \p in {1,...,50}
{ \fill (4*rand,2*rand) circle (0.05);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** I played around with it a little, as I wanted to keep all points inside of the ellipse. The second version generates a random x value and then computes a random y value in such a way that it is inside. As there is less "y space" for extremal values of x, the points cluster at the end points of the major axis. The third is an ellipse in polar form: first, an angle is randomly chosen and the radius is computed to be on the inside of the ellipse. Here, the points cluster at the minor axis and the center, a so called *Gorthaur<sup>1</sup>*-Distribution.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) ellipse (4 and 2);
    \clip (0,0) ellipse (4 and 2);
    \pgfmathsetseed{24122015}
    \foreach \p in {1,...,1000}
    { \fill[black]  (4*rand,2*rand) circle (0.05);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) ellipse (4 and 2);
    \clip (0,0) ellipse (4 and 2);
    \pgfmathsetseed{24122015}
    \foreach \p in {1,...,1000}
    { \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{4*rand}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{rand*0.5*sqrt(16-pow(\x,2))}
        \fill[black]    (\x,\y) circle (0.05);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[inner color=black, outer color=yellow!20!black] (0,0) ellipse (4 and 2);
    \clip (0,0) ellipse (4 and 2);
    \pgfmathsetseed{24122015}
    \foreach \p in {1,...,1000}
    { \pgfmathsetmacro{\t}{360*rnd}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{rnd*4*2/(sqrt(pow(2*cos(\t),2)+pow(4*sin(\t),2)))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{abs(\r)/4*100}
        \fill[yellow!\c!red]    (\t:\r) circle (0.05);
        \typeout{\t, \r, \c}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

[image]

<sup>1</sup>: I totally made this up. *Gorthaur* is a name *Sauron*, the villain in *the lord of the rings*, used in earlier ages ;-) As I usually watch the trilogy with my family over christmas I felt this little joke was in order.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are a master! I search for this!

Comment: @danielg: The `clip` command is very useful. Hoever, all commands following it will be clipped. To keep the effect local, you can put the `clip` and relevant commands in a scope.

Answer (score 10):

Whenever there's a question about filling something with random dots, there *has* to be an answer using [JLDiaz's Poisson Disc Sampling code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185419/poisson-disc-sampling-implemented-in-luatex):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{poisson}
\begin{document}
\edef\mylist{\poissonpointslist{8}{4}{0.1}{20}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \clip (4,2) ellipse (4 and 2);
    \foreach \x/\y in \mylist {
        \fill (\x,\y) circle(1pt);
    }
\end{scope}
\draw (4,2) ellipse (4 and 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

And here's the approach from [Filling specified area by random dots in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145972/2552): 150 equally distributed dots that all lie in the ellipse:

[image]

The equation for the top half of the ellipse is

```
sqrt( 2^2 * (1 - x^2/(4^2) )
```

The [antiderivative of the inverse](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=antiderivative+of+y+%3D+1+%2F+sqrt%28+2%5E2+*+%281+-+x%5E2%2F%284%5E2%29+%29) is

```
2 * asin(x/4)
```

and the scaling factor is `4/pi`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfmathsetseed{3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    axis equal,
    declare function={a(\x) = sqrt( 2^2 * (1 - \x^2/(4^2) );},
    declare function={b(\x) = -sqrt( 2^2 * (1 - \x^2/(4^2) );},
    declare function={f(\x) = 2 * rad(asin(x/4)) * 4 / pi;}
]
\addplot [only marks, samples=150, domain=-4:4] ({f(x) },{rand * ( a(f(x)) - b(f(x)) ) / 2} );
\draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=4, y radius=2];
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Here's the code for an ellipse with `x radius=2` and `y radius=1`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfmathsetseed{3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    %hide axis,
xmin=-4, xmax=4,
    axis equal,
    declare function={a(\x) = sqrt( 1^2 * (1 - \x^2/(2^2) );},
    declare function={b(\x) = -sqrt( 1^2 * (1 - \x^2/(2^2) );},
    declare function={f(\x) = 2 * rad(asin(x/4)) * 2 / pi;}
]
\addplot [only marks, samples=150, domain=-4:4] ({f(x) },{rand * ( a(f(x)) - b(f(x)) ) / 2} );
\draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: However, that does not appear truly random. With that many dots one would expect some clustering and overlaps, right?

Comment: It's not "truly random" in that the points aren't independent, but I think it's prettier than completely random points. It's definitely not "ordered" (i.e. there's no grid structure). Whether this distribution is useful probably depends on the exact use case.

Comment: Yeah, definitely looks nice, I'll remember this for future applications :D

Comment: @Jake Thank you for your answer! Your solution is also good and simple. But I have a little problem with the scaling factor, which you write here. Because I change your code with sqrt( 1^2 * (1 - x^2/(2^2) ) at the specific places (I want to create an ellipse with xRadius = 2 and yRadius = 1). Also I change the scaling factor to 2 / pi, but I get an error. Latex said: ! Missing number, treated as zero ! He write the "addplot - line" as the mistake place. Where is my mistake? If you want, I can post this minimal code.

Comment: @danielg: I've edited my answer to show how to get an ellipse with x radius=2 and y radius=1. Let me know if that helps

Comment: @Jake Thank you very much. Now it works. I'm not sure, but I think it depends on the domain.