# density wave with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

For a presentation on the human hearing I need to create a sketchy diagram representing the behaviour of the air particles when they are passed through by a pressure wave. Something like this:
[image]

Can I make such a diagram with PGFPlots? It allows to draw a randomly distributed marks across a rectangular, but I haven't found out how to change the density of the dots as a function of sin(x).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It would help us a lot, if you could present an MWE of what you have tried already by yourself.  In your case, there are a lot of nice TikZ and PFG-examples on the net around.  Have you found anything usable there?

Comment: @Jan I did my best to find some ready made template or example, including the one provided [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145972/95441). However I was not able to modify it according to my needs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You mean something like the following?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
    \RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % increases compilation speed when using LuaLaTeX
        compat=1.12,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            hide axis,
        ]
            \addplot [
                only marks,
                domain=0:25,
                samples=2001,
                mark size=0.75,
            ] (
                {0.75*sin(deg(x)) + x},
                {rand}
            );
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Nice! Out of curiosity, is there a reason you picked 2001 samples (instead of 2000)?

Comment: @Jake, the "nice" belongs to you. Because this is just a very simplified version of your *awesome* answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145972/95441. No, this is just habit I would say. Because "*normally*", when you want to have "round" numbers, you need let's say 51 samples. From that it went up to 101, then to 1001 and finally ending at 2001 ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I meant! I would never find it out myself...

Comment: @ArtemijKeidan, you are welcome. For your information: If this answer suits your needs you could -- besides [upvoting the answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it) -- also [accept it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: @StefanPinnow I am new to this site, did not realize that I had to vote the answer.