# concentric density waves with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I already posed a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348386/density-wave-with-pgfplots) concerning the plotting of a pressure wave with the help of pgfplot. That question was brilliantly answered by @Stefan Pinnow. The result is shown here:

[image]

Now I would like to introduce an additional feature: the high density zones must be distorted along concentric circular paths with growing radius. I made a prototype of what I mean by distorting the preceding image on Adobe Illustrator:

[image]

But I would like to make a similar plot on pgfplot only. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with [Stefan Pinnow's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348386/density-wave-with-pgfplots), it is rather straightforward to produce a cartoon of concentric circular waves.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % increases compilation speed when using LuaLaTeX
        compat=1.12,
    }
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar}     
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{polaraxis}[hide axis]
          \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
            {\addplot [
                only marks,
                domain=0:360,
                samples=\i*501,
                mark size=0.75,
            ] (
                {x},
                                {\i+0.5*(asin((rand))/(90))}
                );}
  \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a more realistic (but arguably less appealing) wave, just remove the `\i*` after `samples=`.

Comment: Awesome! this does perfectly for my case.