# Random dots with noise component

Tags: graphics

I wonder how to fill specified area by dotted points.I want to fill the green area with green random dots, and instead of  the red area i want to fill it with red random dot, and the white area with blue random dots. 
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
%\usepackage{xcolor,pict2e}% to allow any radius

  \tikzset{pics/myarc/.style args={inner #1 and outer #2 with fill #3}{
  code={
    \draw[very thick, #1] (1,0) arc (0:90:1cm);
    \draw[very thick] (0,1) -- (0,2);
    \draw[very thick, #2] (0,2) arc (90:0:2cm);
    \draw[very thick] (2,0) -- (1,0);
    \fill[#3] (1,0) arc (0:90:1cm) -- (0,2) arc (90:0:2cm) -- cycle;
  }
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick,<->] (-6,0) -- (6,0)node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
\pic [draw,very thick, rotate=-45]      {myarc={inner blue and outer blue with fill green!}};
\pic [draw, very thick, rotate=45]      {myarc={inner blue and outer blue with fill white}};
\pic [draw, very thick, rotate=135]      {myarc={inner blue and outer blue with fill red!40}};
\pic [draw, very thick, rotate=225]      {myarc={inner cyan and outer blue with fill white}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have a look on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145969/4821).

Answer (score 3):

With regular dots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,patterns}
%\usepackage{xcolor,pict2e}% to allow any radius

  \tikzset{pics/myarc/.style args={inner #1 and outer #2 with fill #3}{
  code={
    \draw[very thick, #1] (1,0) arc (0:90:1cm);
    \draw[very thick] (0,1) -- (0,2);
    \draw[very thick, #2] (0,2) arc (90:0:2cm);
    \draw[very thick] (2,0) -- (1,0);
    \fill[pattern=dots,pattern color = #3] (1,0) arc (0:90:1cm) -- (0,2) arc (90:0:2cm) -- cycle;
  }
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick,<->] (-6,0) -- (6,0)node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
\pic [draw,very thick, rotate=-45]      {myarc={inner blue and outer blue with fill green!}};
\pic [draw, very thick, rotate=45]      {myarc={inner blue and outer blue with fill blue}};
\pic [draw, very thick, rotate=135]      {myarc={inner blue and outer blue with fill red!40}};
\pic [draw, very thick, rotate=225]      {myarc={inner cyan and outer blue with fill blue}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Randomizing needs more work and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145969/11232) and its answers should give a a heads up.

And here is an attempt using the strategy of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98759/11232)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,patterns}
%\usepackage{xcolor,pict2e}% to allow any radius

  \tikzset{pics/myarc/.style args={inner #1 and outer #2 with fill #3}{
  code={
    \draw[very thick, #1] (1,0) arc (0:90:1cm);
    \draw[very thick] (0,1) -- (0,2);
    \draw[very thick, #2] (0,2) arc (90:0:2cm);
    \draw[very thick] (2,0) -- (1,0);
    \clip (1,0) arc (0:90:1cm) -- (0,2) arc (90:0:2cm) -- cycle;
    \foreach \x in {1,...,300}
        {
            \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{5}{300}
            \pgfmathrandominteger{\b}{5}{300}
            \pgfmathrandominteger{\c}{30}{30}
            \fill[#3] (0.01*\a,0.01*\b) circle (0.001*\c);
        };
  }
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick,<->] (-6,0) -- (6,0)node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
\pic [draw,very thick, rotate=-45]      {myarc={inner blue and outer blue with fill green!}};
\pic [draw, very thick, rotate=45]      {myarc={inner blue and outer blue with fill blue}};
\pic [draw, very thick, rotate=135]      {myarc={inner blue and outer blue with fill red!40}};
\pic [draw, very thick, rotate=225]      {myarc={inner cyan and outer blue with fill blue}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If `lualatex` is an option, a [Poisson sampling](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185419/poisson-disc-sampling-implemented-in-luatex) would look nice. I'm wondering if a pgf version is hard to implement...